# Can reduceColumns be invoked by other client libary functions in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, reducers, profiler

I am running a script in Google Earth Engine Javascript API with a large feature collection as input, but the execution of the script fails with the error `user memory limit exceeded`. When I run the script with the profiler, it shows that GEE is trying to run a `reduceColumns` operation at the size of 2.5 G of memory:

[image]

The strange thing is: I don't use `reduceColumns` anywhere in my script, also not even in the dependencies I am using. Could it be possible that `reduceColumns` is invoked by another client library function in my script? I ask it as a theoretical question on purpose because I am not in a position to share my script and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several algorithms that aggregate the results of a FeatureCollection end up doing so via reduceColumns, including any of the collection.aggregate_* functions.  If you're doing collection.aggregate_count(...) that's just reduceColumns with a count reducer, wrapped in a simpler to use pacakage.